# PhotoImage is not responding to tkinter Scale widget

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have a python script which allows a user to open up an image in a tkinter canvas widget. The program is printing out the size that the new image should be, but only the original image shows up. How do I refresh the canvas with the new size.

Here is the python code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
factor = 1.0
width_org = 500
height_org = 500
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("600x600")
mGui.configure(background = 'yellow')
frame = Frame(mGui, width = 400, height = 400)
frame.pack(anchor = 'nw')
frame.configure(background = 'red')
canvasframe = Canvas(frame, width = 400, height = 400, scrollregion = (-500,-500,500,500))
hbar = Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill = X)
hbar.configure(command= canvasframe.xview)
vbar = Scrollbar(frame,orient = VERTICAL )
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
vbar.configure(command= canvasframe.yview)
canvasframe.configure(xscrollcommand= hbar.set, yscrollcommand= vbar.set)
canvasframe.pack( expand = True, fill = BOTH)
pil_img = Image.open("rose-flower-500x500.jpg")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
def openit():
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    try:
        pil_img = Image.open(in_path)
    except IOError:
        pass
    width_org, height_org = pil_img.size
    try:
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
    except IOError:
        pass

    canvasframe.create_image(20,20, image = img)
    canvasframe.img = img
valueList = [25, 50, 100, 150, 200]
def valuecheck(value):
    newval = min(valueList, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(value)))
    scalepic.set(newval)
    factor = newval/100.0
    w = int(width_org*factor)
    h = int(height_org*factor)
    print (w, h)
    pil_img = pil_img.resize((w,h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
    canvasframe.create_image(20,20, image =img)
openpic = Button(mGui, text = "Open", command = openit).pack()
scalelabel = Label(mGui, text = "Resize Image").pack()
scalepic = Scale(mGui, from_=min(valueList), to=max(valueList), command=valuecheck, orient = HORIZONTAL)
scalepic.set(100)
scalepic.pack() 

mGui.mainloop()
```

Also, how can I open a new image? I'm thinking of a for loop and some kind of dispose method, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

**EDIT**
Part of code in classes

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


factor = 1.0
width_org = 500
height_org = 500
class MainApp(Frame):
    def createControls(self):
        frame = Frame(self, width = 600, height = 500)
        frame.configure(background = 'red')
        frame.pack(anchor = 'nw')
        canvasframe = Canvas(frame, width = 600, height = 500, scrollregion = (-600,-500,600,500))
        canvasframe.configure(xscrollcommand= hbar.set, yscrollcommand= vbar.set)
        canvasframe.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)
        hbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        hbar.configure(command= canvasframe.xview)
        vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
        vbar.configure(command= canvasframe.yview)


    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, width = 800, height = 600, background = 'yellow')
        self.pack()
        self.createControls()


root = Tk()
app = MainApp(parent =root)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to save the reference to the new PhotoImage in `canvasframe.img`, so it gets garbage collected when `valuecheck` returns.

Also, rather than creating a new Canvas image with `create_image` for the rescaled image you should simply update the existing one via `itemconfig`. To do that, you need to save the item id number returned by `create_image`. Eg, in `openit`, do

```
canvasframe.imgid = canvasframe.create_image(20,20, image = img)
```

And then in `valuecheck`, after you create the new PhotoImage do

```
canvasframe.img = img
canvasframe.itemconfig(canvasframe.imgid, image=img)
```

You don't have to store `img` and `imgid` as attributes of `canvasframe`, but it's convenient in this case. It would get messy though if you had lots of things on the canvas that you had to track. But for larger Tkinter programs it's a good idea to put everything into one or more classes. It makes things more organized, and easier to access.

Comment: Your solution is very helpful. I'm just not sure about the syntax for saving the new Photo Image and saving the ID number

Comment: I tried rewriting my program with classes but keep getting really weird errors saying i didnt define a defined widget or indentation errors when indentation is uniform. Ill add code

Comment: @EricLopez-Reyes It would be better to ask about that class stuff in a fresh question. You can put a link to this one in your new question if you think it will help readers to understand it better.