# How to deal with possible indentation and definition errors in python program with classes

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I wrote a python program with tkinter and pillow libraries where a user can open up an image. They can then zoom in or out on said image with the use of a tk slider. I submitted a question about photoimage output here: [PhotoImage is not responding to python tkinter scale widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460584/photoimage-is-not-responding-to-python-tkinter-scale-widget) and the changes worked. I then tried to rewrite my program using a class MainApp() but this is where i have seemingly inexpicable (to me) definition errors--particularly the tk Canvas canvasframw--and indentation errors. How do I keep this from happening?

Here is the pertinent part of python class code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


factor = 1.0
width_org = 500
height_org = 500
class MainApp(Frame):
    def createControls(self):
        frame = Frame(self, width = 600, height = 500)
        frame.configure(background = 'red')
        frame.pack(anchor = 'nw')
        canvasframe = Canvas(frame, width = 600, height = 500, scrollregion = (-600,-500,600,500))
        canvasframe.configure(xscrollcommand= hbar.set, yscrollcommand= vbar.set)
        canvasframe.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)
        hbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        hbar.configure(command= canvasframe.xview)
        vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
        vbar.configure(command= canvasframe.yview)


    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, width = 800, height = 600, background = 'yellow')
        self.pack()
        self.createControls()


root = Tk()
app = MainApp(parent =root)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post errors you get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elope\OneDrive\Documents\Work Stuff\resizeimage.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MainApp(Frame):
  File "C:\Users\elope\OneDrive\Documents\Work Stuff\resizeimage.py", line 16, in MainApp
    canvasframe.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)                                                                    
NameError: name 'canvasframe' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def createControls(self):
    frame = Frame(self, width = 600, height = 500)
    frame.configure(background = 'red')
    frame.pack(anchor = 'nw')
    hbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
    canvasframe = Canvas(frame, width = 600, height = 500, scrollregion = (-600,-500,600,500))
    canvasframe.configure(xscrollcommand= hbar.set, yscrollcommand= vbar.set)
    canvasframe.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)
    hbar.configure(command= canvasframe.xview)
    vbar.configure(command= canvasframe.yview)
```

Get an IDE (like PyCharm) to avoid definition errors like this.